# How to remember user negative decision at 'beforeinstallprompt' event while asking to install PWA?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I've just made the changes to make Chrome recognize my web application as a progressive web application. I followed the official tutorial at Chrome's Developers website:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/?hl=es

So I have:

```
var deferredPrompt;
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
// Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera 
Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#modalInstallPWA").modal('show');
} // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.


deferredPrompt = e;
}); // Installation must be done by a user gesture! Here, the button click

$("#btn-install-pwa").on('click', function() {
// Show the prompt
deferredPrompt.prompt(); // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt

deferredPrompt.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {
    console.log(choiceResult.outcome);

    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
    } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
    }

    deferredPrompt = null;
});
});
```

So what I would like to is to remember user decision so Chrome is not asking the user over and over again to install the PWA. This works well when the user decided to install the PWA but not in the case the user decided to not install it.

I thought in doing this by the use of a cookie but I wanted to know if maybe there is a built-in feature or a easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you seeing the message a second time after you say no? I believe chrome will not ask again for XX days automatically. UNLESS you totally clear out your browser - like when someone is testing a PWA.

Comment: "Once dismissed by the user, it will not appear again until a sufficient amount of time has passed (currently 3 months). " https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria

Comment: You are right. The problem in desktop version is that you have to make the user do an action to make the install app window prompt. In my case, as you can see in the code I show a modal at beforeinstallprompt event and it is only when the user clicks 'ok' button when Chrome built-in PWA install window prompts.

My question was if it is possible to remember the negative user decision in the point the initial modal is shown, and without the need of prompting the chrome built-in window and making him click in 'Cancel' button.

I'm currently achieving this by the use of a self created cookie

Comment: I see. Probably the best way for now. Hopefully, at some point both in the future desktop and mobile will both work the same. A2HS is an ever-morphing task to keep up with.